How to sort players in puzzles/games across rounds? with extra constraints
I am creating a game where players play puzzles together in x rounds. Now I am having a problem sorting these players across all rounds because I have specific constraints.
Here are the rules/constraints I have for my puzzle.

Every round players play puzzles

Rounds must be equal to the amount of puzzles

Players should play all puzzles

Puzzles have min, max, best player amounts

Players can only play 1 puzzle per round

Players can't play a puzzle again

Puzzles must meet their min players if players are assigned to the puzzle

Player must play a puzzle every round

Not every puzzle has to be played every round


Puzzles should try to be filled up to their best amount
I have created the following in php.
generate player list.
Try to put player in puzzle
Check if player has played this puzzle or puzzle already reached minimum
If player can not be played in any puzzle try again but now with best requirement
If player can't still be placed try again with max requirement.
If a player could not be placed in a puzzle try a different player order/permutation.
After every player is placed check if all assigned puzzle have met their minimum.
If not, try to redistribute those players among the other puzzle with player that did not meet their best and then max requirement.
If this can't be done try  a different player order/permutation.
I tried this with the following players/puzzles:
11 players, 6 puzzles

Puzzle 1:
         min: 2
         max: 5
         best: 4
Puzzle 2:
         min: 2
         max: 4
         best: 3
Puzzle 3:
         min: 2
         max: 6
         best: 5
Puzzle 4:
         min: 2
         max: 4
         best: 4
Puzzle 5:
         min: 2
         max: 8
         best: 6
Puzzle 6:
         min: 2
         max: 5
         best: 3 

And this is one of the results:
Player 1: puzzles played:   5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6
Player 2: puzzles played:   4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5
Player 3: puzzles played:   4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6
Player 4: puzzles played:   1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5
Player 5: puzzles played:   5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 4
Player 6: puzzles played:   2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 4
Player 7: puzzles played:   3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 5
Player 8: puzzles played:   1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4
Player 9: puzzles played:   3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 6
Player 10: puzzles played:  2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6
Player 11: puzzles played:  2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 6

index-round [0]: schedule: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2
index-round [1]: schedule: 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2
index-round [2]: schedule: 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5
index-round [3]: schedule: 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 6, 6
index-round [4]: schedule: 1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 1, 6, 3, 6, 3, 1
index-round [5]: schedule: 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6

How could I improve this so that puzzle are better filled to their best, for example that round 1 (index 0) puzzle are filled to their best.
PHP code:
<?php

class Player
{
    public $id;
    public $puzzlesPlayed = []; // track which puzzles the player has played

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

class Puzzle
{
    public $id;
    public $min;
    public $max;
    public $best;
    public $players = []; // track which players are in the puzzle

    public function __construct($id, $min, $max, $best)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->min = $min;
        $this->max = $max;
        $this->best = $best;
    }
}

class Solver
{
    private $players;
    private $puzzles;
    private $schedule = [];
    private $tries = 8000;
    private $roundTries = [];

    public function __construct($players, $puzzles)
    {
        $this->players = $players;
        $this->puzzles = $puzzles;
    }

    function permutations(array $items, int $length = null)
    {
        $length = $length ?? count($items);

        if ($length === 1) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                yield [$item];
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
                $remainingItems = $items;
                array_splice($remainingItems, $index, 1);

                if (count($remainingItems) > 0) {
                    foreach ($this->permutations($remainingItems, $length - 1) as $permutation) {
                        yield array_merge([$item], $permutation);
                    }
                } else {
                    yield [$item];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Round 0
    public function solve()
    {
        // Round equal to the number of puzzles
        $roundPPI = []; // PPI = Permutations Per (round)Index was used before I changed to shuffling the players array (faster return)
        for ($round = 0; $round < count($this->puzzles); $round++) {
            $roundPPI[$round] = 0;
            $this->roundTries[$round] = [];
        }
        $lastRound = [];

        for ($round = 0; $round < count($this->puzzles); $round++) {
            // Assign players to puzzles

            // Debug progress
            echo chr(27) . chr(91) . 'H' . chr(27) . chr(91) . 'J';
            echo "Calling assignPlayersToPuzzles with index-round $round and ppi " . $roundPPI[$round] . "\n";
            foreach ($this->roundTries as $key => $roundTries) {
                echo "index-round [$key]: has " . count($roundTries) . " tries\n";
            }

            $roundResult = $this->assignPlayersToPuzzles($round, $roundPPI[$round], $lastRound);
            if (!$roundResult) {
                echo "[Fail] Failed in index-round $round\n";
                $this->schedule[$round] = [];
                $round--;
                $roundPPI[$round] = $roundPPI[$round] + 1;
                $lastRound = $this->schedule[$round];
                $this->roundTries[$round][] = $this->schedule[$round]; // save the round to prevent trying the same round again
                $this->schedule[$round] = [];
                $round--;
            } else {
                // Reset ppi for next round if this round was successful
                $roundPPI[$round + 1] = 0; // reset ppi for next round if this round was successful only for backtracking

                // Remove all tries after this round if this round was successful
                for ($r = 0; $r < count($this->puzzles); $r++) {
                    if ($r > $round) {
                        $this->roundTries[$r] = [];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return [$this->schedule, $this->players];
    }

    public function assignPlayersToPuzzles($round, $ppi = 0, $lastRound = [])
    {

        // foreach ($this->permutations($this->players) as $index => $playerPermutation) {
        //     if ($index < $ppi) {
        //         continue;
        //     }
        for ($mainIndex = 0; $mainIndex < $this->tries; $mainIndex++) {

            // Reset players, puzzles and schedule
            foreach ($this->players as $player) { // $this->players / $playerPermutation
                if (count($player->puzzlesPlayed) > $round) {
                    $player->puzzlesPlayed = array_slice($player->puzzlesPlayed, 0, $round, true);
                }
            }
            foreach ($this->puzzles as $puzzle) {
                $puzzle->players = [];
            }
            $this->schedule[$round] = [];

            $playerPermutation = $this->players;
            shuffle($playerPermutation);

            foreach ($players as $player) {
                foreach ($puzzles as $puzzle) {

                }
            }

            foreach ($playerPermutation as $player) {
                // Assign players to puzzles
                foreach ($this->puzzles as $puzzle) {
                    if ($this->isPossible($player, $puzzle, 'min')) {
                        $this->schedule[$round][$player->id] = $puzzle->id;
                        $player->puzzlesPlayed[] = $puzzle->id;
                        $puzzle->players[] = $player;
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
                // puzzle already filled to min try to fill to best

                foreach ($this->puzzles as $puzzle) {
                    if ($this->isPossible($player, $puzzle, 'best')) {
                        $this->schedule[$round][$player->id] = $puzzle->id;
                        $player->puzzlesPlayed[] = $puzzle->id;
                        $puzzle->players[] = $player;
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
                // puzzle already filled to best try to fill to max
                foreach ($this->puzzles as $puzzle) {
                    if ($this->isPossible($player, $puzzle, 'max')) {
                        $this->schedule[$round][$player->id] = $puzzle->id;
                        $player->puzzlesPlayed[] = $puzzle->id;
                        $puzzle->players[] = $player;
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }

                // could not find a puzzle for the player
                continue 2; // main for loop

            } // placed all players in puzzles

            // check if all puzzles have the minimum amount of players
            $minPuzzles = [];
            $puzzlesWithPlayers = [];
            foreach ($this->puzzles as $puzzle) {
                // only check puzzles with players
                if (count($puzzle->players) > 0) {
                    if (count($puzzle->players) < $puzzle->min) {
                        $minPuzzles[] = $puzzle;
                    } else {
                        $puzzlesWithPlayers[] = $puzzle;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count($minPuzzles) > 0) {
                $playersToRedistribute = [];
                foreach ($minPuzzles as $puzzle) {
                    foreach ($puzzle->players as $player) {
                        array_pop($player->puzzlesPlayed);
                        $playersToRedistribute[] = $player;
                    }
                }


                // sort puzzleWithPlayers by how many players are away from their best
                usort($puzzlesWithPlayers, function ($a, $b) {
                    return count($a->players) - $a->best < count($b->players) - $b->best;
                });

                foreach ($playersToRedistribute as $remainingPlayer) {
                    foreach ($puzzlesWithPlayers as $remainingPuzzle) {
                        if ($this->isPossible($remainingPlayer, $remainingPuzzle, 'best')) {
                            $this->schedule[$round][$remainingPlayer->id] = $remainingPuzzle->id;
                            $remainingPlayer->puzzlesPlayed[] = $remainingPuzzle->id;
                            $remainingPuzzle->players[] = $remainingPlayer;
                            continue 2;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach ($puzzlesWithPlayers as $remainingPuzzle) {
                        if ($this->isPossible($remainingPlayer, $remainingPuzzle, 'max')) {
                            $this->schedule[$round][$remainingPlayer->id] = $remainingPuzzle->id;
                            $remainingPlayer->puzzlesPlayed[] = $remainingPuzzle->id;
                            $remainingPuzzle->players[] = $remainingPlayer;
                            continue 2;
                        }
                    }

                    // could not find a puzzle for the player
                    continue 2; // -> assignPlayersToPuzzles
                }

            }

            // check if this round schedule was already tried
            if (in_array($this->schedule[$round], $this->roundTries[$round])) {
                continue;
            }
            return true;
        }
        // var_dump("Tried all permutations in index-round $round with ppi $ppi");
        return false;
    }

    private function isPossible($player, $puzzle, $requirement = 'min')
    {
        if (in_array($puzzle->id, $player->puzzlesPlayed)) {
            return false; // Player has already played this puzzle
        }
        if (count($puzzle->players) >= $puzzle->{$requirement}) { // puzzle->max??
            return false; // Puzzle equals best amount // is full
        }

        return true;
    }
}

$players = [new Player(1), new Player(2), new Player(3), new Player(4), new Player(5), new Player(6), new Player(7), new Player(8), new Player(9), new Player(10), new Player(11)]; // Add more players as needed
$puzzles = [new Puzzle(1, 2, 5, 4), new Puzzle(2, 2, 4, 3), new Puzzle(3, 2, 6, 5), new Puzzle(4, 2, 4, 4), new Puzzle(5, 2, 8, 6), new Puzzle(6, 2, 5, 3)]; // Add more puzzles as needed


$solver = new Solver($players, $puzzles);
$result = $solver->solve();
echo "=======================Final schedule========================== \n";
foreach ($result[1] as $key => $player) {
    echo "Player ".$player->id.": puzzles played: " . implode(", ", $player->puzzlesPlayed) . "\n";
}

foreach ($result[0] as $key => $roundSchedule) {
    echo "index-round [$key]: schedule: " . implode(", ", $roundSchedule) . "\n";
}

A better solution would be great but a step towards the right direction would be awesome. Or maybe a solution to a similar question or problem.

I think first you have to define an evaluation function to measure the quality of a solution (given the other constraints hold). E.g. maximize the amount of games with best player amount or minimize absolute (squared) or relative distance to best. Also the representation of the solution is not sufficient to be clear, e.g. in the last round you don't know if you should do game 6 once with 5 players or twice: once with 3 and once with 2 players.
